# iOS "slide" ViewController

Tags: ios

I'm going to build an app that should present "slide" viewcontrollers , as we can find in Twitter app for iPad or Facebook app.
Is it available any framework or source code to implement this functionality?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot?